# Fourier Sine Integral

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Find the Fourier sine integral of the function defined by
$$
\,\mathrm{f}\left(x\right) =
\begin{cases} \sin\left(x\right) & \text{;}\quad 0 \leq x \leq \pi
\\[1mm]
0 & \text{;}\quad  \ x\ > \pi
\end{cases}
$$
and hence evaluate the integral
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin\left(\pi\omega\right)\sin\left(x\omega\right) \over
1 - \omega^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}\omega\,;\quad x \geq 0
$$

Comment: Done. And you, what have you attempted?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio,I am completely new to fourier.I have tried it on my own,but I failed.If you provide me with an answer,it would be greatful of you.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I have tried to solve the first part using sine integral.But failed to solve the integration.

Answer (score -1):

I think we first need $B(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)\sin \alpha x \, dx$. Then the Fourier integral (sine) is $\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}B(\alpha)\sin \alpha x \, d\alpha$.

Now $B(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin x \sin \alpha x \, dx$. Note that $2\sin x\sin \alpha x=\cos(x-\alpha x)-\cos(x+\alpha x)$. Hence $B(\alpha)=\frac{1}{2}(\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(x-\alpha x) \, dx-\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(x+\alpha x)\, dx)$. So, $2B(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(x(1-\alpha))\, dx-\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(x(1+\alpha))\, dx$. So $2B(\alpha)=\frac{1}{1-\alpha}(\sin(1-\alpha)\pi)-\frac{1}{1+\alpha}(\sin(1+\alpha)\pi)$. So $2B(\alpha)=\frac{1}{1-\alpha}(\sin \pi \alpha)+\frac{1}{1+\alpha}(\sin \pi \alpha)$. So $B(\alpha)=\frac{1}{1-\alpha^2}\sin \pi \alpha$.

Now we need $\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-\alpha^2}\cdot \sin \pi\alpha \sin \alpha x \, d\alpha$. Call this integral $I$. I can't find the value of $I$, but probably someone else can delve into this.

Edit: OK, I see the value of $I$ is what is asked to be found in the next part of the question.